# postgresql logical replication not copy initial data

Tags: postgresql

postgresql logical replication not copy initial data

When replicating a table with around 80,000 rows, the initial data replication works well. However, when replicating tables with millions or tens of millions of rows, the initial data replication doesn't work. How can I resolve this issue?

```
publication

create publication pub_a for table a;
subscription

create subscription sub_a connection "host= ... " pub_a
connection is success
```

but subscriber log:
initial sync started and after few minute, I can see below log

first: could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
and few minute after

remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections

and postgresql make many select command

---

publisher log:
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Comment: How are these 2 machines connected?  "Connection reset by peer" sounds like the networking between them is unstable and causing the transfer to fail

Comment: @Cargo23 um, "How are these 2 machines connected?" what meaning? I connected 2 machines use ssl and it works well small size table

Comment: This is a network issue, could be that it gets lost after some time. Could be seconds, minutes or whatever. Start with the firewall to check the logfiles

Comment: Which machine are those messages showing up on, the publisher or the subscriber?  And whichever it is, what does the log of the other machine say at the same time points?

Comment: @jjanes I edited!

Comment: @FrankHeikens Ok Thanks. but small table logical replication is well done..

Comment: If both sides say the other side hung up, that indicates a networking problem.

Comment: If it works for a table having a small number of records but it doesn't work with a large number of records, time works against you: After X seconds/minutes/hours your database connection gets closed by something. We had something like this, every connection got killed after exactly 3600 seconds, 1 hour. It was the firewall that did this.

Comment: Thank you, everyone. I solved problem. upgrade postgresql 12 to 15

Comment: @how to solve networking problem...?
Do i solve networking problem at postgresql side? or server setting side?